# How to solve the mechanics question written below?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

A string of length 20cm is attached to 2 points A and B at the same level and a distance of 10cm apart. A string of mass 5g can slide on the string and a horizontal force F is applied so the ring is in equilibrium vertically below B.

a) Find the tension in the string

b) Find F, the force applied to maintain equilibrium

The solutions are a) 0.031N and b) 0.025N

I am unable to make sense of the situation on a force diagram. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Gwen this question will be closed under a minute in PSE...ig that's why they asked it here